# Navigation Bar Width via CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress, formatting, styles

I'm trying to set the width of a navigation bar on a Wordpress site via CSS. It should be 52.5em on Mac (Safari/Chrome/Firefox). However, that setting causes the menu to break and wrap into two lines on Windows (IE).

Is there a better way to set the width so that it looks good in all browsers (rather than a static width value)? I tried `width: 100%`, but it did this:

[image]

My CSS is:

`#navigation {
width: 52.5em;
}`

Link: [VET PETS](http://vetpets.org)

Comment: You want width 100%. Remember you must take into account border, margin, etc when doing width 100%. What is the result of width 100%. And remember for width 100% to work I believe it will be 100% of the first parent with a position.

Comment: Setting `width: 100%;` causes the menu to extend to the full page width. It should stop/cut off after Contact Us. See screenshot added to original post.

Comment: You need to base the #navigation width based on the overall width of it's child elements. That way it will always be right.

Comment: It's always going to look funny if you have that UL wrapped in the div with the div having the background color. The right area will always be weird. I would put background color and radius on the UL, and keep the UL centered so that way the entire menu is always centered and you don't have a hanging blue area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ul.nav {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    width: 760px;
    margin-right: 30px;
}
```

width: 760px; !!!!  no auto!!!

use a  devel... tools of firefox Ctrl+Shift+I

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `margin-right: 30px;`in ul.nav , it fixed it for me on ie

Comment: What value did you have for the menu width? I added `margin-right: 0;` as a rule for ul.nav.

Comment: This was before you changed it to `width: 100%`